# Why shouldn't `&apos;` be used to escape single quotes?

Tags: html, escaping, quotes

As stated in, [When did single quotes in HTML become so popular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242766/when-did-single-quotes-in-html-become-so-popular) and [Jquery embedded quote in attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263141/jquery-embedded-quote-in-attribute), the Wikipedia entry on [HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML#Character_and_entity_references) says the following:

> The single-quote character ('), when used to quote an attribute value, must also be escaped as `&#x27;` or `&#39;` (should NOT be escaped as `&apos;` except in XHTML documents) when it appears within the attribute value itself.

Why shouldn't `&apos;` be used?  Also, is `&quot;` safe to be used instead of `&#34;`?

Comment: [`&apos;` is valid in HTML5](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18551371).

Comment: Note that IE8 doesn't support `&apos;`.

Comment: There's a "not" missing from the Wikipedia quote, which should be "… when ***not*** used to quote an attribute value …".

Comment: Oh, so if you don't care about anything older than IE11, `&apos;` is fine.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz But of course it was a valid concern back in 2010, when this question was asked...

Answer (score 220, accepted):

`&quot;` is on the official list of valid [HTML 4 entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html), but `&apos;` is not.

From [C.16. The Named Character Reference '](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_16):

> The named character reference `&apos;`
>   (the apostrophe, U+0027) was
>   introduced in XML 1.0 but does not
>   appear in HTML. Authors should
>   therefore use `&#39;` instead of
>   `&apos;` to work as expected in HTML 4
>   user agents.

Comment: `&quot;` is on the list though, so should be OK.

Comment: Today happened that on an IE8 machine &apos; was not parsed, so the user sees the code.
Replacing with &#39; solved the problem.

Comment: &aquot; is NO substitute for &apos; as one's a single and the other a double.

Comment: FYI: HTML5 does support both entities

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi I assume you mean `&quot;` - there is no such entity as `&aquot;`

Answer (score 50):

`&quot;` is valid in both HTML5 and HTML4.

`&apos;` is valid in [HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref), but not [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html). However, most browsers support `&apos;` for HTML4 anyway.

Comment: Note that IE 8 doesn't support `&apos;`.

Comment: dont shoot me for saying - who cares about IE8...

Answer (score 36):

`&apos;` is not part of the HTML 4 standard.

`&quot;` is, though, so is fine to use.

Comment: How can this be an answer when &aquot; = " not '? It's like suggesting a colon for a semicolon...

Comment: @Richardakacyberkiwi Read the question all the way to the end.

Comment: @Anon.: [`&apos;` is now part of the HTML standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/named-character-references.html#entity-apos).

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi I assume you mean `&quot;` - there is no such entity as `&aquot;`

Answer (score 25):

If you need to write semantically correct mark-up, even in HTML5, you must *not* use `&apos;` to escape single quotes. Although, I can imagine you actually meant apostrophe rather then single quote.

[single quotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark) and [apostrophes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe) are not the same, semantically, although they might look the same.

> *Here's* one apostrophe.

Use `&#39;` to insert it if you need HTML4 support. *(edited)*

In British English, single quotes are used like this:

> "He told me to 'give it a try'", I said.

Quotes come in pairs. You can use:

`<p><q>He told me to <q>give it a try</q></q>, I said.<p>`

to have nested quotes in a semantically correct way, deferring the substitution of the actual characters to the rendering engine. This substitution can then be affected by [CSS rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-quotes), like:

```css
q {
  quotes: '"' '"' '<' '>';
}
```

An old but seemingly still relevant article about semantically correct mark-up: [The Trouble With EM ’n EN (and Other Shady Characters)](http://alistapart.com/article/emen).

*(edited)* This used to be:

> *Use ’ to insert it if you need HTML4 support.*

But, as @James_pic pointed out, that is not the straight single quote, but the "Single curved quote, right".

Comment: The question was clearly about using apostrophes and not quotes. Why would you post this?

Comment: I clearly see _single quote_ in the title. The question was why escaping them should not be done with _&apos;_. I answered this because the support for &apos; is not the only concern.

Comment: Single quotes are used that way in American English, also.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it clarifies that apostrophe and single quotes aren't the same thing and that's why you shouldn't use apostrophes to enclose a HTML attribute value.

Comment: In Unicode, the apostrophe character (&#39;) is classed as a quotation mark, and is the only form of the "straight" quotation mark in the spec. The advice to use &#8217; is at best incomplete, because that is the character for "Single curved quote, right". If you really are going for semantic correctness, it should be used for right quotation marks, while &#8216; ("Single curved quote, left") should be used for left quotation marks.

Comment: Most of this answer has nothing to do with the question, which was about HTML markup syntax, not English grammar.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need single quotes, apostrophes, you can use

```
html    | numeric | hex
&lsquo; | &#145;  | &#x91; // for the left/beginning single-quote and
&rsquo; | &#146;  | &#x92; // for the right/ending single-quote
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question(s) asked.