# Are there differences between XML and HTML special character encoding?

Tags: html, xml, special-characters

Are there any characters that are encoded in HTML but not XML, or vice versa?

Are all the encodings the same between them? Like &gt; for greater than symbol?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

XML does predefine a handful of character entities.  See section 4.6 of the XML 1.1 spec:

http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-predefined-ent

In particular, XML defines `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&amp;`, `&apos;`, and `&quot;` ("All XML processors *MUST* recognize these entities whether they are declared or not").
Any other entities must be referenced via numeric reference, as Brian states, or by an appropriate definition in an `<!ENTITY ...>` construct in the document itself or a referenced DTD.

All of these entities are defined in HTML as well.

Comment: Though as noted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083754/why-shouldnt-apos-be-used-to-escape-single-quotes, the apos escape sequence is NOT part of the HTML spec, and not supported by certain browsers

Comment: @evnafets: "certain browsers" = IE8, the usual suspect

Answer (score 2):

Yes. HTML4 defines a number of named entities which aren't present by default in XML. You can see the [list on the w3.org website](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html). `&gt;` is one such encoded entity. Likewise, `&lt;` is the named entity for `<`, but you can also write it like so: `&#60;`. As far as I know you can use the numbered version freely in both HTML and XML. See the w3.org link for how to define your own entities in XML documents.