# Single quotes in data attribute containing json

Tags: jquery, json

Cosmetic question:
I have a html element containing possible dimensions for some embedded images, these are stored as:

```
<div class="inside" data-dimensions='{ "s-x": 213, "s-y": 160, "m-x": ...
```

I get out the data-dimension and parse with jQuery.parseJSON(jQuery.data("dimensions")) all fine and closely following the jquery's doc.

However I'm used to encapsulate all my html attributes inside double quotes:

```
<div class="inside" data-dimensions="{ 's-x': 213, 's-y': 160, 'm-x': ...
```

But then I get a malformed json exception. Are there ways so i can obey my self imposed "double quoted html attributes" law?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `&quot;` instead of `"`. But quoting orgies are horrible (in HTML even more than in PHP) so better go with single-quoting your html attributes.

BTW, you do not need to use `.parseJSON` - jQuery does that automatically if the `data-` attribute starts with `{` (actually, it's more complex - here's the regex it uses to test if it should be parsed as JSON: `^(?:\{.*\}|\[.*\])$`).

Comment: thanks for pointing out the parseJSON error. I just came back here for pointing out that parseJSON was wrong after all. If I had come back earlier it would have saved me some time.

Comment: After a long time not understanding why the the JSON in my `data-` attribute wasn't being parsed as JSON, I realized it has to be perfectly formed JSON, including **quotes around property names**. Hope this saves someone some time. http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5

Comment: Thanks to this answer I now know why jQuery doesn't parse my JSON when it's indented... it's the final newline that doesn't match the regex.

Comment: How would I manage quotes inside the values of the json object in the attribute? `<div data-dimension="{ 'value': '10' 12"' }`

Comment: You HTML-encode them, i.e. `&quot;` (single quotes are not allowed in JSON)

Answer (score 9):

The **[JSON specification](http://json.org/)** stipulates that keys and (string) values be quoted with double-quotes.

**[HTML attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2)** can be enclosed in either single or double quotes.

Personally, I wouldn't fight it and just go with what causes the least amount of friction and is easiest for all to understand which in this case is to single quote the HTML attributes and use double-quotes inside the attribute value.

Answer (score 9):

Try this and you can keep nicely formatted JSON in the attribute:

```
$.parseJSON($('.inside').data('dimensions').replace(/'/g,"\""))
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `&quot;` instead of `"` and `&apos;` instead of `'`.

Comment: You should not use &apos; you should use &#39; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083754/why-shouldnt-apos-be-used-to-escape-single-quotes

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the function `eval` or create a new function. You can use either `"` or `'` in your JSON and you don't need to put `"` around the keys in the JSON object.

```js
let el = document.getElementById('example');
let person = (new Function(`return ${el.dataset.person}`))();
console.log(person);
person.age++;
console.log(person.age);
```

```html
<div data-person="{name:'Natalie Portman',age:35}" id="example"></div>
```