# Why does this regex/DOM character entity tester return `undefined`?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, dom, character-entities

```
var str = 'let us pretend that this is a blog about gardening&cooking; here&amp;apos;s an apostrophe &amp; ampersand just for fun.';
```

This is the string I'm operating on.  The desired end result is: `"let us pretend that this is a blog about gardening&cooking; here&apos;s an apostrophe &amp; ampersand just for fun."`

```
console.log('Before: ' + str);


str = str.replace(/&amp;(?:#x?)?[0-9a-z]+;?/gi, function(m){
  var d = document.createElement('div');
  console.log(m);
  d.innerHTML = m.replace(/&amp;/, '&');
  console.log(d.innerHTML + '|' + d.textContent);
  return !!d.textContent.match(m.replace(/&amp;/, '&')[0]) ? m : d.textContent;
});


console.log('After: ' + str);
```

Comment: You have `!!` at the beginning of your return. I don't believe that is valid syntax, and if it is, I think it cancels itself out.

Comment: @Shmiddty `!!` is used to cast an operand to a Boolean. It's valid syntax and I dont think it is related to the issue.

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding) may have some answers for you. HTML encoding is one of those things where you should reuse a proven solution instead of trying to roll your own.

Comment: Nope... the "inner" (second) one converts it to a boolean expression, (and, like you say, inverts it), the second one re-(un-)inverts it. That's the idea, to cancel it out without having cumbersome nested parentheses.

Comment: I'm not sure what your point of matching the first character of that de-`&amp;`ed string is, could you explain what you intend with that?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that HTML doesn't support XML's `&apos;`
To avoid the issue you should use `&#39;` instead of `&apos;`

For more information look at this post:

[Why shouldn't `&apos;` be used to escape single quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083754/why-shouldnt-apos-be-used-to-escape-single-quotes)

Comment: That definitely isn't the issue.  The section containing &apos; is working just fine, exactly the way I want it to.  What's not working is `&amp;amp;`.

Comment: Okay, maybe you just need to use more simple function like this:
str = str.replace(/&amp;/gi, function(m){
  console.log(m);
  return m.replace(/&amp;/, '&');
});

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
str.replace(/&amp;([#x]\d+;|[a-z]+;)/g, "&$1")
```

or, with a positive lookahead:

```
str.replace(/&amp;(?=[#x]\d+;|[a-z]+;)/g, "&")
```

I don't think you need any HTML2text en-/decoding.