# IE 8 issue with &apos; &amp;

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer

I have ruby on rails program running in my local system and i used `html_safe` tag, now `&amp;`  `&apos;` are not present in FF, chrome but still present in IE 8 only

Comment: Uh... what? What are you trying to do? Show your code.

Comment: i have an input L &amp; T it should displayed L & T only IE not display this chrome and firefox works fine

Comment: works fine for &amp; => & but not for &apos;=>'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't \`&apos;\` be used to escape single quotes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083754/why-shouldnt-apos-be-used-to-escape-single-quotes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Numbered HTML entities are better supported across browsers than named entities.

Use the following numbered entities:

`'`  →  `&#39;`

`&` →  `&#38;`