# Why I can't use the org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils to convert this String containing character as &apos and &egrave?

Tags: java, string, escaping, stringescapeutils

I am trying to do some experiment with the **org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils** class but I am finding some difficulties.

I have the following situation in my code:

```
String notNormalized = "c&apos;&egrave;";

System.out.println("NOT NORMALIZED: " + notNormalized);
System.out.println("NORMALIZED: " + StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(notNormalized));
```

So first I have declared the **notNormalized** field that (at least in my head) have to represent a not normalized string that contains an **apostrophe** character represented by the **'** and an **accented vowel** represented by the **è** (that should be the **è** character)

Then I try to print it without normalization and I espect that is print the **c'è** string and the its normalized version and I expect to retrieve the **c'è** normalized\converted string.

But the problem is that I still obtain the same output, infact this is what I obtain in the console as output:

```
NOT NORMALIZED: c&apos;&egrave;
NORMALIZED: c&apos;&egrave;
```

Why? What am I missing? What is wrong? How can I perform this test and correctly convert a string that contains character as **&apos** ?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking to do is [`unescapeHtml4`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4%28java.lang.String%29).

So

```
System.out.println("NORMALIZED: " + StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(notNormalized));
```

which prints

```
NORMALIZED: c&apos;è
```

Unfortunately, [`&apos` is not an HTML 4 entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083754/why-shouldnt-apos-be-used-to-escape-single-quotes) and therefore can't be unescaped with this tool. You can use [`unescapeXml`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeXml%28java.lang.String%29) for the `&apos` but not for the `&egrave`. You'll have to mix and match.

Comment: It say that it don't recognize the unescapeHtml4() method

Comment: @AndreaNobili You must be using an older version of apache commons. Upgrade to version 3 if possible.

Comment: @AndreaNobili Version 2 has a [`unescapeHtml`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29) method, but I'm not sure if it's a mix of HTML 3 and 4.