# Single invited comma in JavaScript function parameter not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am calling JavaScript function which has two parameter. Everything working fine, but when any parameter having single invited comma its not working. I have tried to replace it with \' but still not working. My codes are.

Server Side :

```
string param1 = "IFES";
string param2 = "IFES Chapter's Introduction";
string str = param2.Replace("'","\'");
btnShow.Attributes.Add("onclick","ShowDetails('" + param1 + "','" + str + "')");
```

JavaScript Code:

```
function ShowDetails(prm1,prm2){
     // My code here
}
```

Comment: I'd rather use JSON'ing instead of adjusting the params here. Still, replace for `\\'` instead should do.

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083754/why-shouldnt-apos-be-used-to-escape-single-quotes or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004168/escape-quotes-in-javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The single backslash is being eaten by the compiler; you need to double up

```
string str = param2.Replace("'","\\'");
```