# How decode [&apos;] to ' in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

I use this code:

```
 Dim str= Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&apos;")
```

But it not working.
Result : `str="&apos;"`

Comment: Your code does convert this on my machine...Have you added System.Web as a reference in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3):

`&quot;` is on the official list of valid HTML 4 entities, but `&apos;` is not.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2083770/831138

So you should probably do a correction (`yourString.Replace("&apos;","&quot;")`) before the Decode.

Comment: Only this character "&apos;", or exist other character have to replace?

Comment: @DT All those that are not present in the specification, I presume: https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html (could be any).